# Empty EditText error (Lots of EditTexts)

Tags: android, android-edittext

The activity contains a lot of EditTexts (about 40) where the user enters numbers, and then they're added. But when one of these EditTexts is empty, it gives an error and the app stops. I've read lots of solutions, but I don't want to write code for each EditText.

Here is some code (Wrote 450 lines, don't gonna show them all, but all of them are similar)

```
EditText mark1;
EditText mark2;
EditText mark3;
EditText mark4;
EditText mark5;
TextView marksem1;
Button calcsem1;
double mark1calc=0;
double mark2calc=0;
double mark3calc=0;
double mark4calc=0;
double mark5calc=0;
double totalsem1=0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.etsia_gia_ata_layout);
    initControls();

private void initControls() {

    // Course 1 sem 1 calc
    mark1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.mark1);
    mark2=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.mark2);
    mark3=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.mark3);
    mark4=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.mark4);
    mark5=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.mark5);
    marksem1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.total1calc);
    calcsem1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.total1);
    calcsem1.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener()
      {public void onClick
      (View  v) {calcsem1();}

    private void calcsem1() {
        mark1calc=Double.parseDouble(mark1.getText().toString());
        mark2calc=Double.parseDouble(mark2.getText().toString());
        mark3calc=Double.parseDouble(mark3.getText().toString());
        mark4calc=Double.parseDouble(mark4.getText().toString());
        mark5calc=Double.parseDouble(mark5.getText().toString());
        totalsem1=(9*mark1calc+6*mark2calc+6*mark3calc+6*mark4calc+3*mark5calc)/30;
        marksem1.setText(Double.toString(totalsem1));
        marksem1.setText(String.format("%.2f", totalsem1));
    }});
    }
}
```

Hope there's a solution. Thank you very much!

Comment: Please post your error code

Comment: What do you want to happen when one of the EditTexts is empty?

Comment: @cygery I'd like to treat it as its value is equal to zero.

Comment: Then I suggest using Mark Ormesher's solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem comes from the fact that `Double.parseDouble(...)` on an empty string will throw a `NumberFormatException`. You could replace each line with somthing like this:

```
try {
    mark1calc = Double.parseDouble(mark1.getText().toString());
} catch (NumberFormatException e) {
    mark1calc = 0;
}
```

This is a lot of extra code, so I'd suggest implementing something like this:

```
public static Double safeParse(String input) {
    try {
        return Double.parseDouble(input);
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        return 0d;
    }
}

// ...

mark1calc = safeParse(mark1.getText().toString());
mark2calc = safeParse(mark2.getText().toString());
mark3calc = safeParse(mark3.getText().toString());
// ...
```

(This assumes you want an empty box to be worth 0; you can adjust the default value to your needs)

Comment: They certainly do. I'd recommend making your method static though :)

Comment: Terrific suggestion. Will edit for future generations.

Comment: Looks good! But.. does private void calc1sem() affect the code?

Comment: @Isaías: Nope, you can just replace each `Double.parseDouble(...)` with `safeParse(...)`

Comment: @MarkOrmesher thank you, but it shows me an error in "safeParse(String input)": The method safeParse cannot be declared static; static methods can only be declared in a static or top level type. Quick fix: Remove 'static' modifier of 'safeParse(..)'

Comment: Where is all this code being placed? Could you show me the whole document, please? Use something like Pastebin if it's too long

Comment: @Isaías: Okay, I see the problem. You've defined `safeParse` within your `onClickListener`, but this won't work because inner classes (like the listener) cannot have static methods or fields defined. If you move the whole `safeParse` method up by about a dozen lines and put it before `private void initControls()` (or somewhere else as a direct child of your `ETSIAGiaATA_Activity` class) then you should be fine. :)

Comment: @MarkOrmesher: It works! I didn't realize I was placing safeParse inside initControls(). Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

I assume your problem is with parseDouble. You can write your own protected parseDouble, which will try-catch to parse the text, and if an exception is thrown, will just return zero.

Something like this:

```
private static double safeParseDouble(String text)
{
    try 
    { 
        double result = Double.parseDouble(text);
        return result;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: It might be worth catching only `NumberFormatException` - catching every single exception runs the risk of disguising more serious errors like NPEs. Debatable though, in this instance.

Comment: That's a good point. It had occurred to me, but in this case I thought it was in the user's best interest to catch everything that may have went wrong and keep the flow going. I do agree that in general, catching any and all exceptions is dangerous.

Answer (score 0):

`Double.parseDouble()` can throw exceptions so you will need to use `try-catch` block.

```
try {
    mark1calc=Double.parseDouble(mark1.getText().toString());
    mark2calc=Double.parseDouble(mark2.getText().toString());
    mark3calc=Double.parseDouble(mark3.getText().toString());
    mark4calc=Double.parseDouble(mark4.getText().toString());
    mark5calc=Double.parseDouble(mark5.getText().toString());
    totalsem1=(9*mark1calc+6*mark2calc+6*mark3calc+6*mark4calc+3*mark5calc)/30;
    marksem1.setText(Double.toString(totalsem1));
    marksem1.setText(String.format("%.2f", totalsem1));
} catch (Exception e) {
    // handle errors...
}
```

Comment: This will lose all the numbers following the line the throws the exception, and will not calculate anything since the parsing happens before the calculation. It will prevent the app from crashing but will not solve the problem.

Comment: He may want to skip calculations if any `EditText` is empty ;) He didn't say anything about how to handle error.

Comment: Since what his app is doing is summing up all the numbers in the EditTexts, it's reasonable to assume he wants to ignore the empty fields but have his app still function.

Answer (score 0):

you can replace your parsing statement with terinary statement as below:

```
mark2calc = mark4.getText().toString().equals("") ? 0 : Double.parseDouble(mark4.getText().toString());
```